# Google Time Based Graphs can't be seen as images

Tags: python, charts

I have a chart that is a time based chart. However when I try to publish it as a image - it doesn't seem to physically publish. I get link and when I `inspect` link I can see the image, but the image is just a blank when you look at the site. I thought this was a browser specific issue - but alas, tried it on linux/microsoft O/S and different browsers - same result - the image is blank.

The interactive version of the graph seems to be working from the get go, in all o/s and browsers.

Is there way to bypass this and have a time-based chart display as an image?

**Addendum:**
The type of graph is as follows:[image]

The x axis is time and y axis is any relevant value. The graph  events that has happened at a given time instant. However with most if not all Google charts, when you click the publish button you have the option to publish the graph as an image or an interactive graph: [image]

However with time-based graphs you still get this option but when you choose to publish it as an image, and go to the published website - there is nothing to be seen there - it's just blank. I have tried different o/s and browsers but no success.

Is there a way to publish the time-based graph as an image that can actually be seen?

Comment: It's difficult to visualize what you are describing without any code, error logs, or screenshot.

Comment: Retracted my downvote. :) Delete all these comments? Will delete mine in a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

This should not have a google-visualization tag. It looks like you are have created a chart in Google docs and are trying to use their 'publish to the web' feature. That is separate from the Google visualization API.